# n-dimensional space: Does a line intersect a simplex or not?

Tags: geometry

in an n-dimensional space a line (defined by 2 points) and a simplex (defined by n+1 points) are given. I'm looking for a boolean criterion to check wether the line intersects the simplex or not. 
Thank you very much for your help and kind regards, 
Goetz

Comment: Check this question - it is something along the same lines, although they check for points (specifically 0), not lines. But you will definitely need this for the computation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819132/how-do-i-check-if-a-simplex-contains-the-origin

Comment: Line or line segment ?

Comment: a line (not a segment)

Comment: May be there is a way using linear optimization ...